# How to load markers from XML file with directions API in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to load markers from XML file on a map used for outputing directions. Basically, it's the combination of two demos found on Google's documentation pages.

Directions: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel

XML: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/xmlparsing/downloadurl_info.html

I have first created the directions map and then tried to add XML file that contains markers.

I'm probably making a simple mistake, but since I'm not good with js and coding, can't find what. There are no errors displayed, only a blank page.

Here is my current code:

```
<script>
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523)
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));
    var control = document.getElementById('control');
    control.style.display = 'block';
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP].push(control);
  }   
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  downloadUrl("http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/xmlparsing/moredata.xml", function(data) {
  var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
    var marker = createMarker(markers[i].getAttribute("name"), latlng);
   }
 });

  function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
    var request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Here is the (non-working) jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ajJ3u/

Comment: Did you get any of the 2 demos to work before combining them?

Comment: Do you have anything in the markers array that you are filling via the data.documentElement......?  I would step to that point guessing you don't have data there

Comment: @davidstrachan Yes, both of the demos work when used separately

Comment: @UserSmith No, I don't. I have noticed that only one of the things gets outputed. It's either markers from XML or the directions service. What gets displayed depends on the order of the functions in the code. Tha last one is displayed.

Comment: I have added a jsFiddle address in the edit. Posting it here too: http://jsfiddle.net/ajJ3u/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems from a quick review:

1. you are creating the map twice.
2. you don't have a createMarker function. If that call came from one of the examples, you missed bringing it to the new map.
3. downloadUrl is subject to a cross-domain security restriction. If your page is not running in the "http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com" domain, it won't work.  You need to access xml from the same domain as the page is running in or use a proxy.

[Example of directions from/to markers from xml (translated to v3 from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map4c.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! The example showed me the way. I have some problems left, but I have asked for the solutions in another question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799380/how-to-add-multiple-separated-with-a-plus-symbol-waypoints-to-a-map-and-dynami.