# How to add multiple (separated with a plus symbol) waypoints to a map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Thanks to [geocodezip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789153/how-to-load-markers-from-xml-file-with-directions-api-in-google-maps) , I have managed to create a map with directions functionality and XML markers loaded. There is a problem left though:

How can I add waypoints to it? They should be separated by plus symbol or something else appropriate.

Here is the current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
 // global "map" variable
var map = null;
var rendererOptions = {
draggable: true
};
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
// A function to create the marker and set up the event window function 
function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latlng,
map: map,
zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
});
var contentString = html;
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
}
// ===== request the directions =====
function getDirections() {
// ==== Set up the walk and avoid highways options ====
var request = {};
if (document.getElementById("walk").checked) {
request.travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING;
} else {
request.travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING;
}
if (document.getElementById("highways").checked) {
request.avoidHighways = true;
}   
if (document.getElementById("alternatives").checked) {
request.provideRouteAlternatives = true;
}   
// ==== set the start and end locations ====
var saddr = document.getElementById("saddr").value
var daddr = document.getElementById("daddr").value
request.origin = saddr;
request.destination = daddr;
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
}
});
}
function initialize() {
// create the map
var myOptions = {
zoom: 8,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.907787,-79.359741),
mapTypeControl: true,
mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
navigationControl: true,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
myOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
infowindow.close();
});
// Read the data from example.xml   
if (document.getElementById("showmarkers").checked) {
downloadUrl("example.xml", function(doc) {
var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
// obtain the attribues of each marker
var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
var html = markers[i].getAttribute("html");
var label = markers[i].getAttribute("label");
// create the marker
var marker = createMarker(point,label,html);
}
});
}
// Read the data from example2.xml   
if (document.getElementById("showmarkers2").checked) {
downloadUrl("example2.xml", function(doc) {
var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
// obtain the attribues of each marker
var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
var html = markers[i].getAttribute("html");
var label = markers[i].getAttribute("label");
// create the marker
var marker = createMarker(point,label,html);
}
});
}
}
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
{ 
size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
});  
//]]>
</script>
```

This is the code I have used to generate waypoints, but it's not working now:

```
var via = document.getElementById("via").value;
  if (via) {
      so = via.split("+")
      if (so.length > 1) {
          var wpArray = [];
          for (i=0; (i<so.length); i++) {
            wpArray.push({location: so[i], stopover:true})
          }
          request = {
            origin:saddr, 
            destination:daddr,
            waypoints: wpArray,
            provideRouteAlternatives: true,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
          }
      } else {
          request = {
            origin:saddr, 
            destination:daddr,
            waypoints:[{location:via, stopover:true}],
            provideRouteAlternatives: true,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
          }
      }
  } else {
      request = {
        origin:saddr, 
        destination:daddr,
        provideRouteAlternatives: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      }
  }
```

EDIT This is the working function:

```
function getDirections() {
        // ==== Set up the walk and avoid highways options ====
        var request = {};
        if (document.getElementById("walk").checked) {
           request.travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING;
        } else {
          request.travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING;
        }

        if (document.getElementById("highways").checked) {
           request.avoidHighways = true;
        }

        if (document.getElementById("alternatives").checked) {
           request.provideRouteAlternatives = true;
        }


        // ==== set the start and end locations ====
        var start = document.getElementById("start").value
        var end = document.getElementById("end").value

        request.origin = start;
        request.destination = end;
        request.waypoints = via;

var so;
var via = document.getElementById("via").value;



if (via) {
      so = via.split("+")
      if (so.length > 1) {
          var wpArray = [];
          for (i=0; (i<so.length); i++) {
            wpArray.push({location: so[i], stopover:false})
          }
          request = {
            origin:start, 
            destination:end,
            waypoints: wpArray,
            provideRouteAlternatives: true,
            avoidHighways: document.getElementById("highways").checked,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
          }
      } else {
          request = {
            origin:start, 
            destination:end,
            waypoints:[{location:via, stopover:false}],
            provideRouteAlternatives: true,
            avoidHighways: document.getElementById("highways").checked,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
          }
      }
  } else {
      request = {
        origin:start, 
        destination:end,
        provideRouteAlternatives: true,
        avoidHighways: document.getElementById("highways").checked,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      }
  }

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: 1. what have you tried for adding waypoints? 2. What do you mean be "separated by a plus symbol or something appropriate"? Where? 3. You should really only ask one question at a time.

Comment: @geocodezip 1. Before I have used the code added in the question edit. However, it's not working now with the new code. 2. The text entered in waypoints text box would look e. g. like this "Paris + Amsterdam", meaning that it should calculate the route through both of the cities (sometimes more than two). 3. I have opened a new question for markers :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802617/how-to-show-hide-markers-from-xml-file-without-refreshing-the-page

Comment: Please post more complete code and specific error messages.  "not working" is not enough detail.

Comment: @geocodezip There are no error messages. It is simply not working, there is nothing happening when I click the submit button, neither with from or to locations nor with stopovers. I'll try to experiment a bit more and then post the whole code.

Comment: You will need to include enough information that we can reproduce the issue, sample xml data as well as sample waypoint that you are testing with.

Comment: @geocodezip I have managed to make it work now. Honestly, I'm not sure what made it function properly, it could be the line "request.waypoints = via;", because before I didn't add "request.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you have 2 xml files or what their format is.  Here is an example which shows/hides markers based on their categories (again translated from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial):

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html

(also copied to [How to show/hide markers from XML file without refreshing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802617/how-to-show-hide-markers-from-xml-file-without-refreshing-the-page) with the part of the question it applied to)

Comment: The second part of the question is now here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802617/how-to-show-hide-markers-from-xml-file-without-refreshing-the-page

Comment: I can't programatically create all of the items in only one xml file, due to big differences in items used for the map. I would have to manually insert every item which is a big problem if you have hundreds of items that change often.