# How to show/hide markers from XML file without refreshing the page

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a map described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799380/how-to-add-multiple-separated-with-a-plus-symbol-waypoints-to-a-map-and-dynami).

Markers from XML files are loaded only if the checkbox is checked. When you uncheck it, they are still displayed until the page is refreshed. How is it possible to show/hide them when the checkbox value is changed? Simple

```
onclick="initialize();"
```

doesn't work and would be very inefficient anyway.

I can't avoid having two xml files and can't use one file with categories instead of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example which shows/hides markers based on their categories (again translated from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial):

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html

Write code to add a category for each of the XML files.

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful! I have inspected the code, but will have to leave this for the future, because it seems way beyond my current knowledge about Google Maps. I have tried to copy some parts, but then there are not any markers displayed.